# set etag of cdn javascript files

Tags: javascript, iis-7, web-config, cdn, etag

I am running my web application developed in .net in IIS 7.0. I have configured in my web.config to set the etag of resources. Its seem to work fine for all resources except these 2 which are javascript files from a CDN:

```
* http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
* http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js
```

I set etags by:

```
 <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear/>
            <!-- Add custom etag  -->
            <add name="ETag" value=" "/>

        </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Is there any way of setting the etage for the 2 external cdn javascript files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fully outside your control. Basically, the ajax.microsoft.com serveradmin is the only one who can change this.

If the Etag is really that important for you, I'd suggest to look for another CDN which serves Etags along. For example, jQuery's own CDN.

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the new microsoft cdn does include etags:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js

[image]